# Creating a CCScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using Spritebuilder to develop a cocos2d application. I want to programmatically create a CCScrollView `scroll` that loads a layer, `Shop.ccb` that I created with SpriteBuilder. `Shop.ccb` is just a CCNode that contains a few UI elements. Before, I used to just create all of it in Spritebuilder, but now I need to do it by adding `scroll` to the parent container.

**How I used to do it:**
[CCScrollView `scroll`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqpOE.jpg)
and [CCNode `Shop.ccb`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfOzA.jpg)

Now, I want to do it programmatically, which is what I am having trouble with.

This is my code so far:

```
CCNode *shopNode = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Shop"];
[shopNode setContentSizeInPoints:(CGSizeMake(320, 1000))];
CCScrollView *scroll = [[CCScrollView alloc]initWithContentNode:shopNode];
[scroll setContentSizeInPoints:(CGSizeMake(320.0, 370.0))];
[scroll setHorizontalScrollEnabled:NO];
[scroll setPosition:(CGPointMake(0, 70))];
[scroll setScrollPosition:(CGPointMake(0, 370))];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene addChild:scroll];
```

When I run the program, I cannot scroll. It does not let me scroll up or down, even though vertical scroll is NOT disabled. When I remove `[scroll setContentSizeInPoints:(CGSizeMake(320.0, 370.0))];`, only then does it let me scroll up and down. Also, it isn't the correct size. It isn't confined to a 320x370 area, it takes up the entire screen. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: try adding the scroll node to runningScene just after creating and before setting its properties (position and content size).

Comment: Ahh that worked! Thanks, feel free to submit it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the scroll node to runningScene just after creating and before setting its properties (position and content size).